# Waterline save time in microseconds

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

The problem is to store timestamps with microsecond precision.

What's the way to store time in microseconds using javascript's waterline ORM?

Comment: You already have time in microseconds and you want to save it to db?

Comment: Yes, exactly. like: 2016-10-13 17:09:23.869662+00